# Cognito sign-up not asking for email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have configured a cognito user pool where currently we are registering the users through a manual process.

I want to allow any user to sign up by their own, and verify their account using email. However, after activating "Enable self-registration", cognito asks only for username and password:

[image: Sign up]

and if the user fills in this, then it creates an "Unconfirmed" user, but he's redirected to `/error` with a generic message "An error was encountered with the requested page.".

I'm guessing this is because Cognito wants to verify the user but it doesn't have the email address, but it's because it didn't ask it in the first place.

I have enabled:

- Allow Cognito to automatically send messages to verify and confirm
- Attributes to verify: Send email message, verify email address
- Self-service sign-up self-registration

I can't edit "Required attributes", which maybe it's what's needed. But it says it can only be set when creating the user pool, and I don't want to delete the one I currently have.

It feels like there should be a way of adding this to the self-hosted sign-up form but I can't find it. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cognito user pool has to have Email selected for the sign in options when it is created. Unfortunately, there is no way to go back and change this on an existing pool, it must be done on creation.

[image]